# can mvprintw(), curses function work with usual ascii codes?

Tags: ascii, ncurses, curses, extended-ascii, pdcurses

I've developed a little console C++ game, that uses ASCII graphics, using cout for the moment. But because I want to make things work better, I have to use pdcurses. The thing is curses functions like printw(), or mvprintw() don't use the regular ascii codes, and for this game I really need to use the smiley characters, heart, spades and so on.

Is there a way to make curses work with the regular ascii codes ?

Comment: Can you post an simple example and the output its giving you? It's likely a problem with your terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of characters like the smiley face as "regular ASCII codes", because they really aren't ASCII at all. (ASCII only covers characters 32-127, plus a handful of control codes under 32.) They're a special case, and the only reason you're able to see them in (I assume?) your Windows CMD shell is that it's maintaining backwards compatibility with IBM Code Page 437 (or similar) from ancient DOS systems. Meanwhile, outside of the DOS box, Windows uses a completely different mapping, Windows-1252 (a modified version of ISO-8859-1), or similar, for its 8-bit, so-called "ANSI" character set. But both of these types of character sets are obsolete, compared to Unicode. Confused yet? :)

With curses, your best bet is to use pure ASCII, plus the defined ACS_* macros, wherever possible. That will be portable. But it won't get you a smiley face. With PDCurses, there are a couple of ways to get that smiley face: *If* you can safely assume that your console is using an appropriate code page, then you can pass the `A_ALTCHARSET` attribute, or'ed with the character, to `addch()`; or you can use `addrawch()`; or you can call `raw_output(TRUE)` before printing the character. (Those are all roughly equivalent.) Alternatively, you can use the "wide" build of PDCurses, figure out the Unicode equivalents of the CP437 characters, and print those, instead. (That approach is also portable, although it's questionable whether the characters will be present on non-PCs.)